# bell in Emacs shell

Tags: shell, emacs

In `M-x shell`, when the bell character is printed (such as in `echo -e '\a'`), it doesn't make any noise and prints out `^G`. Is it possible for it to actually ring the bell like it does in a normal terminal?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get the bell to beep when control-G characters are sent to the shell by evaluating this code:

```
(defun beep-on-alert-char (str)
  (if (string-match-p "\x7" str) (beep)))

(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'beep-on-alert-char)
```